# Friendship paradox demonstration

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

I should demonstrate the [friendship paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_paradox) using the graph theory in this way:

The social network graph is represented by an adjacency matrix $a_{ij}$ ($m$ is the number of edges, $n$ is the number of vertex and $k_i$ is the degree of the i-th vertex).

We define:

- the average number of friends: $m_1 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} k_i $
- the average number of friends of the friends: $m_2 = \frac{1}{2 m} \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} k_j $ (we divide by $2m$ because in undirected graph $\sum_i k_i = 2m$)

I should demonstrate that $m_1 \leq m_2$

I demonstrated the particular case of complete graphs (in that case $m_1=m_2$), but I would something more general. Any help is appreciate!

Answer (score 5):

I'll take "I should demonstrate..." literally.  Thus I'll give some hints.

- By the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), $$2m=\sum_i k_i.$$  So, in order to show $m_1 \leq m_2$, it is sufficient to show $$\frac{1}{n} \Big(\sum_i k_i\Big)^2 \leq \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} k_j.$$
- We know $a_{ij}=0$ unless there's an edge between $i$ and $j$.  We can use this to simplify the right-hand side above.
- You should arrive at an inequality that is equivalent to the one above, which follows from the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).